# PhpMyAdmin Error 500 on table strucure page

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using PhpMyAdmin for a while on my Debian VPS but recently it started to make Error 500 when accessing the "Structure" tab for the tables (`tbl_structure.php` page)... and only this !

```
Error in processing request
Error code: 500
Error text: Internal Server Error (rejected)
It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.
```

Debian 10 / Apache 2.4.38 / PHP 8.0.1 / mysqlnd 8.0.1 / PhpMyAdmin 5.0.4deb1~bpo10+1

I gave all permissions to the user on the databse, it not solved the problem. Looking in firebug, the header for `phpmyadmin/tbl_structure.php` is "500
Internal Server Error" BUT the response is a complete JSON, so it seems data are well sended by the server, but the client probably see the 500 error and not process it.

Has anybody can help with that ? Thank you

Comment: Are there any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: I didn't see any error log relative to this problem but perhaps there is some log out of /var/log/ I didn't see

Comment: The problem occur also with tbl_tracking.php

Comment: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16620 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found! As I mentionned on https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16620

I followed this Symfony bug solution https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/8e34978e4e2c4bf7dac97e44e904368c4cfb54f8

I added `array_value` on line 1177 of `usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php` and everything work now!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see on the version this is the Debian bug ([980375](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=980375)) and you will need to remove and re-install the phpMyAdmin package.

(it could be another error but I think it is most likely to be the Debian bug)

As I said on the issue tracker, [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16620)

Comment: I'm not sure if its just me or everyone using Mac but I face the issue right on the home page after login. PHP 8.0.12; PHPMyAdmin 5.1.3; Firefox 99.0.1; Apache 2.4.51. PHPMyAdmin Installed using composer. The `phpmyadmin/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php` within the phpmyadmin directory already has the patch discussed (`array_values`). It's just the annoying popup everytime though. All functionality seems to work fine.